# DAX to check if value in table is contained in unrelated table POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, contains, selectedvalue

I have the following table

[image]

which I am going to filter through a slicer. Let's say I selected fund AAA.

and I would like to add a column in the following table

[image]

to check whether the CPTY is contained in the CONCAT column for the selected fund.

a dax formula to calculate the column with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedvalue() in order to select know which value is on the filter